# Добавить поле count из другой модели (DRF)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет! Есть объект Post, у которого свой serializer и viewset. У этого объекта есть значение brand и name.

Мне необходимо создать отдельный сервис, который будет выдавать -

```
{ 
   brand: String //Имя самого бренда из `Post`
   count: Int // Здесь должно выводиться сколько под именем Brand есть в сервисе, который отдает `Post` объекты
   image: URL //Изображение, которое никак не связано с объектом Post. Здесь необходимо будет самому добавлять изображение. Получается, null = true, так как по дефолту изображения там не будет
}
```

На иностранном stackoverflow мне овечали на вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533653/count-objects-using-django-rest-framework

Но теперь мне необходимо добавить к этому сервису кастомное поле с изображением. Как это реализовать?